# Is there a way to populate nested relations in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

Already had a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085678/strapi-cms-fetch-nested-content), but it didn't seem to work for me.

### Problem

So in the video (referenced below) at [9:58](https://youtu.be/cvL204xus1w?t=598), he gets the Menu but the **Section DOES NOT HAVE LINKS**. **Is there a way to populate them from the Menu?**

### Where it comes from

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvL204xus1w) from Strapi on Youtube in which he creates a Menu.
The Menu has the following components:

- Link (many)
- Dropdown (many)

Also, a **Dropdown** has a **one-to-many relation** with **Section**, which **contains multiple Link** components.

Something like this:

[image: Menu schema]

Thanks.

Comment: There is a plugin that allows you to "?populate=deep". https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-populate-deep, personally i'm not a fan, it can cause very slow api calls. but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to build a custom controller in order to populate nested relations in strapi.

Only solution that I found working is [this](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/9078#issuecomment-758292245).