# nest populate with media model in strapi

Tags: mongoose, nested, strapi, populate

I have these two models with M2M relation

- `portfolio`
- `portfolio-types`

Inside `portfolio` there's a media field which uses `s3` at the moment called `feature_image`.
This media field contains lots of other attributes and the only attributes I need in return are `url, width, height`

I am trying to query from `portfolio-types` to populate `portfolio` and inside portfolio, I only want to show the three fields as mentioned above `url, width, height` but I cannot see to make it work.

By the way, I already read some other posts such as

[Strapi CMS: Fetch Nested Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085678/strapi-cms-fetch-nested-content)

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4996

but none of them seem to work

sample of what I tried

```
await strapi.query('portfolio-type').model
      .findOne(query)
      .select('name')
      .populate([{
        path: 'portfolios',
        select: 'title',
        populate: {
          path: 'upload',
          select: 'url'
        }
      }]);


/* tried all these below */

      .populate({
        path: 'portfolios',
        select: 'title',
        populate: {
          path: 'upload',
          select: 'url'
        }
      });

      .populate({
        path: 'portfolios',
        select: 'title',
        populate: {
          path: 'feature_image',
          model: 'upload',
          select: 'name'
        }
      });

      .populate({
        path: 'portfolios',
        select: 'title feature_image.url',  // gives collation error caused by mongo version 4.4 and above
      });
```

I mighted a few other ways which I might forgot because I was finding results online and kept on trying until I really can't seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance for any help and advices.